# How to trigger build on one repo by listening to change on another repo

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I have two repos in distinct organizations, repo A and repo B. I have a Github webhook on repo A that is triggered during push events on the repo, and I have a Jenkins job that has a "Github hook trigger for GITScm polling" as a build trigger.

I am looking to trigger the Jenkins build when there is a change to repo A, and I want the job to build from repo B.

I can successfully build from repo A by setting Github project and Source Code Management portions of the Jenkins job to point to repo A. I was hoping that pointing the Github project to repo A and Source Code Management to repo B would do what I wish, but when I do this the build job is never triggered. Is what I'm looking to do possible?

Also, how can I see which branch was pushed to and triggered the job from within my Jenkins jobs?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this using pipeline

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, Once any push event happens in Repo A, it will trigger the one Jenkins job  (ie. Job-RepoA) in Jenkins server via webhook.

Now you want to create one more Jenkins jobs (i.e Job-RepoB) for Repo B and add this job as post-build action in Repo A job (Job-RepoA).

For set up the post-build action use the [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)

Comment: Hm I see. Does this mean that the repo listed as the project repo and the one listed in Source Code Management must match?